Maintaining collection structure when appending assets with Geometry Nodes modifiers applied to them
I marked an object as an asset. It has a complex Geometry Nodes modifier that uses "object info" and "collection info" nodes to import other objects.
These referenced objects are organized neatly in different collections in the outliner. However, when I append this asset into a new, empty file using the Asset Browser, the original structure in the outliner gets messed up. A bunch of objects ends up in the main collection instead of their original collections.
How can I organize these referenced objects so they stay neatly organized when I append them with the Asset Browser?
Images for clarification:



Hello. When you append an asset it also appends all the data blocks it is using. For example if you append a material which uses image textures, it will also append the image textures otherwise the material wouldn't work anymore. Same for modifiers, if you append an object which has a boolean modifier, it will also append the object used as a modifier in your scene.

I think it's a bit less smart though if you have objects or collections set as default values in your modifier inputs. They may get appended too even if not used

Hello and welcome. Please avoid text written inside images, always prefer typing it directly in the body of the post instead. Image content can't be indexed and thus can't be searched for nor readily found by anyone looking for solutions in the future. Updates are difficult because it can't be easily edited in case of mistakes, nor updated in case of future changes. It doesn't follow the fonts and style of the website automatically, and doesn't work with screen readers.

@DuarteFarrajotaRamos I'm sorry, I was not aware. I will pay attention to that.

@Gorgious Hi Gorgious, thanks for your reply again. And apart from not setting collections or object as "default" in the modifier panel, would you have any other tips on keeping things tidy in the outliner when they are to be used with the Asset Browser?

Unfortunately no, AFAIK the collection structure is dissociated when you append an asset. The only thing you can do is create a new collection, select it and append your asset so that all newly potentially unwanted object are placed in the new collection and not in your scene collection

@Gorgious Ok, I see. It would be best to do it that way then.
And would there be a way to hide all these objects and collections from the outliner while they can still be used by the GeoNodes modifier? I mean: not just by toggling off visibility in the viewport or render, but really invisible unless something is turned on to see it?

Why don't you link your asset? that way the object/collections required don't get imported

You can exclude the collection in the outliner, this will effectively collapse all these objects into a single entry in the outliner.

@Leander Link the Geometry Nodes object from the asset browser you mean? In that case I am not able to edit it anymore it seems like. Or do you mean: only link all the data blocks it consists of? Is that possible?

@Gorgious That sounds interesting. Do you mean I could "Exclude from view layer" the unwanted collections in the original file? I have tried that and it doesn't seem to make a difference. All the objects and collections are still imported in the same way.

Yeah no you can't since all the assets that are used are imported without hierarchy. I mean once they are imported in a collection you can exclude this collection

Would there be a way to solve these issues by creating an addon? (controlling how the assets are imported in the outliner with a dedicated collection/ controlling visibility of all these assets/ reusing data properly/ ...) ?
